# Using XGboost for time series prediction

Tags: time-series, forecasting, prediction, boosting

Can we use XGboost to do predition in time series data ? Could anyone explain the logic of mathematics behind that ?

Comment: [Yes you can](http://ellisp.github.io/blog/2016/11/06/forecastxgb) but traditional time-series tools (ARIMA, ETS etc.) would probably give you better results.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I recommend reviewing this package, its documentation and citations:

https://github.com/ellisp/forecastxgb-r-package

Keep in mind, XGB does not typically outperform current time-series methods such as exponential smoothing or ARIMA.